# AngularJS - Using ternary operators and filters within a binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, ternary-operator, angular-filters

I current have a simple data binding:

```
{{ myAccount.Balance }}
```

I think applied a couple of filters:

```
{{ myAccount.Balance | filter1 | filter2 }}
```

However, i want to use a ternary operator when the Balance is less than zero, the below works (without the filters):

```
{{ myAccount.Balance > 0 ? myAccount.Balance : myAccount.Balance + 'minus' }}
```

How can i use my filters 1 and 2 in the above too?

Answer (score 12):

You need to wrap them in parenthesis `()` to take precedency

```
{{ (myAccount.Balance > 0 ? myAccount.Balance : myAccount.Balance + 'minus') | filter | filter 2 }}
```

Comment: although the above now uses the filters, it doesnt add the 'minus' text.

Comment: @OamPsy Whats the result of `myAccount.Balance` when you are expecting `minus` to be concatenate.

Comment: It shoudld display "£3000 (minus)"

Comment: @OamPsy So the actual `myAccount.Balance` result is `£3000`? If so do you see any errors in console

Comment: The actual result is -3000, so £-3000.... I add the £ (but will do that later.. One of the filter removes - (minus symbol).. This is where i want the text (minus) to appear.

Comment: @OamPsy If you print the values without any filters you should see the `minus` string. It may be one your filters converting it a integer which cause it to remove string character.